# least-squares estimation

Tags: mathematical-modeling, least-squares

I want to write a computer program that findes the least-squares estimates of the coefficients in the following models:

1) $y = ax^2+bx+c$

2) $y= ax^n$

can you help me what should I do?I don't have any data of these models.

Comment: What does "least-squares estimates" mean?

Comment: @barak manos this is one of the way to find the best model in model fitting.
I think in this way we select the model as the best model which sum of the squares of deviation in it is minimum.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is linear in the parameters
($a, b, c$).
If your data points are
$(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^m$,
what you want to do
is minimize the sum
$S 
=\sum_{i=1}^m (y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))^2
$.

For each parameter
(for example, $a$),
differentiate $S$
with respect to $a$.
This will get an equation.

In the example,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}
&=\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial }{\partial a}(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m 2(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))\frac{\partial }{\partial a}(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m 2(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))(-x_i^2)\\
&=-2\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2(y_i-(ax_i^2+bx_i+c))\\
&=-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2y_i-\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2ax_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2bx_i-\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2c\right)\\
&=-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2y_i-a\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^4-b\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^3-c\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Setting this
partial derivative to zero,
we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2y_i
=a\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^4+b\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^3+c\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2.
$$

This is one of the
three equations in $a, b, c$
that are needed.

Do the same with
$\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}
= 0
$
and
$\frac{\partial S}{\partial c}
= 0
$.

Then solve these three
linear equations for
$a, b, $ and $c$.

This is the least squares method.

(2) is linear in $a$
but nonlinear in $n$.
You can make it linear in its parameters
by writing
$\ln(y) = \ln(a)+n \ln(x)
$.
Then the parameters
are $\ln(a)$ and $n$.

Anyway, this is a start.

Linear least squares,
like problem (1),
are a lot easier than
nonlinear least squares
like problem (2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Can you help me how can I write a program for this question? and I don't have any data how can I do to have data?

Comment: You should be able to write the program yourself. Also, if you do not have data, what are you fitting?

Comment: I want to solve project 1 in page 11 of https://web.njit.edu/~bose/Data-fitting-part2.pdf there is no data. this is for the best model subject of model fitting